# How to use Ruby to load qtruby4 on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, qt, windows-10

I wish to use Qt on Windows 10 and am currently trying to use the `qtbindings` gem.

When trying to `require 'Qt'` I get the following error:

```
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/qtbindings-4.8.6.5-x64-mingw32/lib/Qt4.rb:25:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/qtruby4 (LoadError)
```

I tried uninstalling the gem and reinstalling it just in case but no luck.

I am using Ruby 2.6.5p114 and qtbindings 4.8.6.5. I made sure that Ruby and the gems are all in the path environment variable.

Am I missing a step or am I using out of date versions?

Comment: Try Ruby 2.5.7 instead. It might not support 2.6.

Comment: good idea, will try